# Migrate data into MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Online using SSIS

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a scenario where I need to use SSIS to migrate data into Online MS Dynamics CRM 2013. Can any give me a rough idea how to do this without using any 3rd party tools?

My understanding is there is no CRM Dynamics Adapter that comes with SSIS that I can use.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way you can use SSIS to import data to CRM. Take a look at a detailed walkthrough here: http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2012/11/integrating-crm-2011-using-sql.html

The guide is written for SSIS 2012 and CRM 2011, but with a few adjustments, it should also work if you are using CRM 2013. The gist of it is you can add the CRM 2013 assemblies (download them [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321)) and call the CRM 2013 web service in one of the SSIS data flow tasks.

It will take a bit of C# coding and mapping of the columns. Without using 3rd party tools (like Scribe) you will have to code up the column mapping yourself. The site I linked has a class ready for you to use, but you will definitely need to modify it for your needs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use [SSIS Integration Toolkit](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm). It doesn't required to write any piece of code. Recheck [articles](http://danielcai.blogspot.ru/search/label/SSIS%20Integration%20Toolkit) that describe how to use Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar solution: [Insert, update and delete records in CRM 2013 with SSIS 2012](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/01/insert-update-and-delete-records-in-crm.html)

Comment: This is the method i am using, however, due to single call per row is causing service timeout exception. I am going to give bulk create a go from filip's post.

Comment: right, both method are giving me a bunch of TimeOut errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions suggested by Philip and Joost work fine but they are not optimal from the performance perspective. See here for a more efficient solution:
http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2014/04/ssis-integration-with-dynamics-crm.html